# Choice between 'teenage' and 'elementary-level'

Tags: word-meaning, indefinite-article

Could someone possibly have a look at this sentence for me, please?

> My strong passion for education stems from my experience with Jack Liu, **a teenage English learner** whom I tutored during my freshman year.

Info: Jack was a fifth-grader and 11 years old back then.

Would it be appropriate to use 'teenage' here? Can I use 'a elementary-level English learner' here instead?

(PS: I am applying for elementary education graduate program.)

Comment: From Simple English Wikipedia: "A teenager, or teen, is a young person whose age falls within the range from 13–19. They are called teenagers because their age number ends with "teen"."

Comment: Wow, that is inspirational. Now I really understand the word 'teen age' Thank you~.

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with your application! (0:

Comment: Some possible rephrasing: "Jack Liu, a pre-teen English language learner", "Jack Liu, a fifth grader learning English", "Jack Liu, an 11-year-old learner of English".

Comment: Wow, I really haven't  thought about the word 'pre-teen' before, I think this word fits more here. BTW, is this word formal enough for writing?

Comment: You might want to use **ESL** instead of **English learner**

Answer (score 4):

"My strong passion for education stems from my experience with Jack Liu, **a fifth-grade English learner** whom I tutored during my freshman year," would be most precise and sound the most natural to my native American English ear. If you specify his grade level, then his age becomes less important. However, *if his age is important to you,* then **"an eleven-year-old English learner"** would be just fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Teenagers** are considered to be over than **10**, in their teens, however it usually refers to those **13** and above, due to how school class rankings are in the US.

An **11-year old** would be considered to be in **middle school** (AmE) or **secondary school** (BrE). **High school** (AmE) begins at **14 years old**.  Not to be confused with the **middle school** system in China.

So your choice between **elementary** or **teenager** is mostly mutually exclusive. To say **teenager** would be taken to mean someone **older** than Jack, to say **elementary** might mean someone **much younger** than Jack.  Jack happened to fall in the middle.

Comment: But he was a fifth-grader. In the States, is Grade six the start of middle school in general?

Comment: Since grade level groupings can vary, it may be best to just refer to him as an **11-year old**. It will probably be commonly understood what ability level Jack had.

Comment: Thank you so much, Peter. And between the word 'pre-teen' and the word ' 11-year-old', may I ask, which one do you prefer?

Comment: Pre-teen would indicated anyone younger than 10, so if you want to imply you may have been teaching a 5 year old, than you can use that. **11 year old** is your best bet. You will find teachers are usually very specific in how they describe their students since different abilities are expected at different ages with no room for ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. and may I ask, would the reader possibly assume that this boy has learnt English language for 11 years? ( by the word ''11-year-old'')

Comment: If you say Jack is a teenager, they might assume he already knew alot, if you say Jack is in elementary school, they may assume you could not teach him much being so young, 11 years old is a good age where it is possible to **really** teach a language. You should say how Jack improved his understanding or pronunciation

Comment: @GraceGao "11-year-old English language learner" will **not** be taken to mean "a learner of English for eleven years". *X-year-old* denotes an age, not a duration.

Comment: Peter's first definition of "teenager" is easily refuted by a simple Google search. A teen is explicitly defined as a person from ages 13-19. I don't think the correct definition is even influenced by the school system. It's more of cultural attitude of people ages 13-19 (kids undergoing the maturation process to adulthood) versus people ages 9-13 (bigger children, but not maturing yet).